# Stored procedure found on localhost but can't be found when published

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

I have a stored proc on a server. The same server is used in both local development and the remote Dev server I have.

The site functions fine when I run it in debug on my local machine. When I publish it returns:

> The stored procedure 'vts_spUserGetUserIdFromUserName' doesn't exist. 
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The stored
>   procedure 'vts_spUserGetUserIdFromUserName' doesn't exist.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [InvalidOperationException: The stored procedure
>   'vts_spUserGetUserIdFromUserName' doesn't exist.]
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.DeriveParameters() +3962
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters(SqlCommand
>   command) +127
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Database.DiscoverParameters(DbCommand
>   command) +154
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.ParameterCache.SetParameters(DbCommand
>   command, Database database) +114
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Database.AssignParameters(DbCommand
>   command, Object[] parameterValues) +42
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Database.GetStoredProcCommand(String
>   storedProcedureName, Object[] parameterValues) +70
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Database.ExecuteScalar(String
>   storedProcedureName, Object[] parameterValues) +38
>   Votations.NSurvey.SQLServerDAL.User.GetUserByIdFromUserName(String
>   userName) +226
>   Votations.NSurvey.WebAdmin.NSurveyAdmin.UserControls.LoginBox.ValidateCredentialsButton_Click(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e) +168
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +11761917
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument) +150    System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +6016

The stored proc is definitely there. I have KDiff'd the two web.config files and there are no differences.
The only issue I can think of is that on the server it is in a Web Application as a sub application of another root site. Could that be the reason. It is inheriting database connection strings from the other application? If so is there any way I can stop that behavior?

Comment: I tried <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false"> </location> around the connection strings in the parent app. But although it took them away from the inherited connection strings in IIS it didn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the schema under which the Stored Procedure is created.

I might be possible that the Stored Procedure is created under your account, that is why when you are running it on local machine its able to find the SP and not when its running under some other account on sever.

Comment: That did it. The Network Service didn't have permission to use the SP so it wasn't seeing it. Slightly misleading error message then saying it didn't exist!